# Linux Command to make columns separated by multiple delimeters

Tags: linux

Want to convert the following pattern

ab
cd
de
fg      as

'ab','cd','de','fg' using unix / linux command .

----Guys -------- The patern is as following

QRTC1065173134
QRTC3988977812
QRTC0889556882
QUTR1641276912
ABCD1763495154
QRTC3991601819

and this is the required pattern   'QRTC1065173134','QRTC3988977812','QRTC0889556882','QUTR1641276912','ABCD1763495154','QRTC3991601819'

Comment: checked for tr, sed and paste but only got the result as the columns separated by single delimeter.

Comment: It is not a pattern. Nonsense, unclear question.

Comment: Could you give a more precise description of your pattern? is it always just 2 characters or any length? Is the delimiter always a single space? or just any number of spaces? Or maybe even any number of white spaces?

Comment: Hi Mmgross,, the pattern is not always of 2 characters . It is of any length. Actually the pattern is 
cd
de
ef

Comment: Where is the _pattern_? Is it in a file?  Is it in a variable? Do you want it replaced there, or output to a new file or variable?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments that it's a bit unclear but, for fun sake:

```
A="ab cd  ef gh   "
echo $A | sed -e "s/^\s*/'/; s/ \{1,\}/','/g; s/\s*$/'/g"
```

Since the question wasn't precise, I only worked on spaces & string boundaries. So it will work with any number of characters, separated  space(s). The result is also trimmed at both ends.  HTH.

Comment: Thanks . But actually the pattern is as following . 
cd
ef
gh

Comment: I am not sure I understand you mean that ther is a dot and dash ? can you be more precise please ?

Comment: sorry for not coming back sooner, but this sed pattern works for the pattern you shown, I think. The two other answers are correct too.

Answer (score 0):

From the clarification, it seems that this is what you want.

```
$ echo "QRTC1065173134 QRTC3988977812 QRTC0889556882 QUTR1641276912 ABCD1763495154 QRTC3991601819"  | sed -E "s/ /', '/g" | sed -E "s/$/'/" | sed -E "s/^/'/"
'QRTC1065173134', 'QRTC3988977812', 'QRTC0889556882', 'QUTR1641276912', 'ABCD1763495154', 'QRTC3991601819'
```

Here "E" is for extended regex so that we do not need to escape the regex metacharacters.

COMMENT 1: Removing an extra whitespace is left as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, that you have groups (e.g. ab bc de ...) separated by spaces, where you want to include a `'` at the beginning/end of everything, and replace the spaces with `','` then `sed` can handle this with relative ease. Below `ab` `cd` ... can be any string of characters, such as `QRTC1065173134`. There are several ways to piece together a matching regular expression, but the following is fairly simple:

```
sed -e "s/\s/','/g" -e "s/^/'/" -e "s/$/'/"
```

**example**

```
$ echo "ab cd de fg hi" | sed -e "s/\s/','/g" -e "s/^/'/" -e "s/$/'/"
'ab','cd','de','fg','hi'
```

or

```
$  echo "QRTC1065173134 QRTC3988977812 QRTC0889556882" | sed -e "s/\s/','/g" -e "s/^/'/" -e "s/$/'/"
'QRTC1065173134','QRTC3988977812','QRTC0889556882'
```